# How to add tooptionsarray in this argument layout grid magento2? What code need to be added in this argument to show as disable and 1 as enable

Tags: magento2, grid

```
  <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="request_status">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">request_status</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="options">text</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your code, replace the following

```
<argument name="type" xsi:type="options">text</argument>
```

By

```
<argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
<argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Request\Status" />
```

The create a file under the following directory structure

> Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Request\Status.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Request;

/**
 * Request Status config options provider
 */
class Status implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * Options getter
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [['value' => 1, 'label' => __('Enabled')], ['value' => 0, 'label' => __('Disabled')]];
    }

    /**
     * Get options in "key-value" format
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        return [0 => __('Disabled'), 1 => __('Enabled')];
    }
}
```

I hope this helps